# Rails test data, in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

This might be a basic misunderstanding on my part. I have a bunch of logic in my app which collects sets of data from several tables and combines them into memory structures. I want to write tests for that logic.

It seems to me that fixtures, factory girl and similar tools build in-memory model instances. If I do activerecord calls, like `Model.find(foo: 12)` won't those apply only against records that were saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, I agree with @mrbrdo's opinion:  prefer rpsec's stub method. but as a rails programmer, I think you have to know both the "fixture" and the "stub".

Fixtures, whatever the `yaml` file or the `factory girl data` , will both save into database. see your `config/database.yml` file for the location where they are. Actually this is useful when you want to make sure that there is ALWAYS some data in the DB during your test, such as an "admin user" with a fixed ID.

Stubs, it's faster than fixture since it won't be saved into DB, and maybe very useful when you want to perform a test that can't implemented by "Fixtures".

So, I suggest that you try both of them in your real coding life, and choose either of them according to the real context.

Comment: Just to add, even if you need an admin user in all your tests, you still don't necessarily need fixtures or a DB, or stubs. You could have a before(:each) with AdminUser.new username: ...
It depends on the way you use this admin user (if it really needs to be in the database), but even then you can usually get away with it if you use nulldb. The only real downside to not using the DB is that it usually takes you a little more time to write tests like that, but in most cases the tests will be better overall (faster and more isolated).

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is not true, fixtures or factory girl **will** use the database. I would avoid fixtures, though, people don't usually use them nowadays.

The proper way to really write your tests would be to stub out activerecord calls, though, because this will make your tests a lot faster. What you want to test is combining data into your structures, not pulling data out of the database - that part is already tested in activerecord's tests.

So stub out the finders like this (if you are using rspec):

```
Model.should_receive(:find).with(foo: 12) do
  Model.new(foo: 12, other_attribute: true)
end
```

So when the method you are testing calls Model.find(foo: 12) it will get

```
Model.new(foo: 12, other_attribute: true)
```

This is much faster than actually creating it in the database and then pulling it out, and there is no point in doing this for what you are testing - it's not important. You can also stub save on the instance and so on depending on what your method is doing. Keep in mind, retrieving data from DB and saving to DB is all already tested in activerecord's tests, there is no point for you to re-do these tests - just focus on your specific logic.

Comment: Thanks!! Followup... My case involves 4 tables, that are intricately connected to each other with 4 belongs_to,has_many pairs. (Basically 3 tables are indexes along row, column and page, and the fourth model represents a value. Point is, there would be a ton of subtle stubbing... I see the advantage in speed but I am as likely to make a mistake in writing the stubs as I would in the actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but you only need to stub what you actually use in the code you're testing. So if you're not calling some association then you don't need to stub it.
Another tool you can use if you want to have fast tests like this is nulldb: https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb. You could use FactoryGirl.build and nulldb together for associations as well.
Of course you can just create the records in the database and that will work fine (e.g. with factory_girl), it'll just be slower.

Answer (score 1):

FactoryGirl supports several build strategies, including one where records are saved to the database.

It's straightforward: `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)` will create a *foo* and save it to the database, whereas `FactoryGirl.build(:foo)` will only create the in-memory version of that object.

More information is available about build strategies here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md , in the "Using factories" section.